# Is it possible to disable background fade of CATransition?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, catransition

Given the following:

```
let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault)
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
    navigationController.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

`viewController` transitions from the bottom to the top just like a modal transition/segue. However, as the view controller makes its way up, the background begins to fade to black (to cover the old view). Is there any way to disable that fade from occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: You just change the colour of the UIWindow